# Installscript CopyFile Function Error

Tags: installscript, installshield-2011

I am trying to copy a file using Installscript copy file function:
bRet=CopyFile( szUnattendIni, szStatusFile );

where the file referred by szUnattendIni is passed as command line argument.
When I pass this file from commandline using double quotes, bRet returns an error saying "System cannot find the file specified"...but when I pass the same name without double quotes, it works fine.

I tried adding a check before copying to verify whether source file exists using:
    if(Is( FILE_EXISTS,szUnattendIni)) then
       MessageBox("File Exists",INFORMATION);
    endif;

In both the cases, the message box is displayed saying the file exists.
I want to support paths with directory name containing spaces for which double quotes is required. But I am not able to. How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it is an issue with the Installscript CopyFile function.
Refer to the link below:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q105860